# Почему не удается сделать обратное преобразование данных из Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

Пишу сервис на Express с библиотекой mongoose и базой MongoDB. Я пытаюсь сохранить схему материнской группы в базу. В материнской группе есть параметр дочерние группы, это массив в котором содержатся айдишники указывающие на объекты схемы дочерней группы

Схема дочерней группы

```
const {Schema, model} = require('mongoose ')

const ChildGroup = new Schema({
  groupId: {type: String, required: true},
  groupName: {type: String, required: true},
  priority: {
    type: Number, required: false, validate: {
      validator: function (v) {
        return 0 < v <= this.study_fields.length;
      },
      message: props => `${props.value} is greater than study_fields length`
    }
  }
})

module.exports = model('ChildGroup', ChildGroup)
```

Схема материнской группы

```
const {Schema, model} = require('mongoose')

const MotherGroup = new Schema({
  groupId: {type: String, required: true},
  childGroups: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ChildGroup'}],
})

module.exports = model('MotherGroup', MotherGroup)
```

Функция обрабатывающая запрос:

```
        const { groupId, childGroups } = req.body;
        const existingMotherGroup = await MotherGroup.findOne({ groupId });
        existingMotherGroup.childGroups = childGroups.map((group) => new ChildGroup({
          groupName: group.groupName, // имя группы - обязательное поле
          groupId: group.groupId, // идентификатор группы - обязательное поле
          priority: 1, // приоритет можно не указывать
        }));
        console.log(existingMotherGroup.childGroups)
        await existingMotherGroup.save();
        const motherGroup = await MotherGroup.findOne({groupId});
        console.log(motherGroup)
        const asd = await motherGroup.populate({path: 'childGroups', model: 'ChildGroup'})
        console.log(asd.childGroups)
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Child groups added to existing mother group' });
```

Собственно console.log(asd.childGroups) выводит мне пустой массив. В то время как const motherGroup = await MotherGroup.findOne({groupId});, содержит параметр childGroups, в котором есть айдишники.

Как вытащить именно объекты из базы, а не айдишники ?

Сразу скажу, что при console.log(existingMotherGroup.childGroups) массив childGroup отображается нормально, то есть сохраняется корректно, так что скорее всего дело не в этом